# Understanding Many-to-Many relationships in MongoDB and how to dereference collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I've spent some time researching MongoDB alternatives for implementing a many-to-many relationships including several stackoverflow articles ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336700/mongodb-many-to-many-association) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117854/many-to-many-mapping-with-mongoose)) and [these](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/schema-design-basics-1) slides.

I am creating an app using the MEAN stack and I'm trying to get confirmation on my schema setup and best practices in dereferencing a collection of objects.

I have a basic many-to-many relationship between users and meetings (think scheduling meetings for users where a user can be in many meetings and a meeting contains several users).

Given my use case I think it's best that I use referencing rather than embedding. I believe (from what I've read) that it would be better to use embedding only if my meetings had users unique to a single meeting. In my case these same users are shared across meetings. Also, although updating users would be infrequent (e.g., change username, password) I still feel that using a reference feels right - although I'm open to opinions.

Assuming I went with references I have the following (simplified) schema:

```
var MeetingSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill in a description for the meeting',
    trim: true
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill in a location for the meeting',
    trim: true
  },
  users: [ {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  } ]
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    }
});
```

First, you will notice that I don't have a collection of meetings in users.  I decided not to add this collection because I believe I could use the power of a MongoDB find to obtain all meetings associated with a specific user - i.e.,

```
db.meetings.find({users:ObjectId('x123')});
```

Of course I would need to add some indexes.

Now if I'm looking to deference my users for a specific meeting, how do I do that? For those who understand rails and know the different between [:include and :join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins) I'm looking for a similar concept.  I understand we are not dealing with joins in MongoDB, but for me in order to dereference the users collection from the meeting to get a user's first and last name I would need to cycle through the collection of id's and perform some sort of a db.users.find() for each id. I assume there's some easy MongoDB call I can make to get this to occur in a performant way.

Comment: If you have all the users' ids in a particular meeting you would just do a single find against users collection to get their names: db.users.find({id:{$in:<list-of-ids-from-meeting>}},{firstName:1,lastName:1}) in essence.  Why would you not just store first and last name of the user in the user array in meetings collection?

Comment: Thank you. So it sounds like I have to do a separate (single) query to get the users using the $in operation - which I guess is fine although I wonder if I could combine the two queries into one (getting the meetings and the user's first and last names)? The reason I'm not just storing the first and last names is that I would have to update those in the rare last of a user changing their name. I imagine that's an ok tradeoff meaning I should just store those and deal with the rare case.

Comment: exactly - why optimize for something that *might* happen - plus do you really need to update a name of a person in a meeting that already took place?  I would think that if they attended that meeting as Joe Shmoe, it shouldn't be changed *after* the fact because now he's known as Joe Doe...  Even if you do want to change it, it's a single "multi" update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a discussion of schema design in MongoDB, covering *exactly* this topic, I refer you to these postings on the MongoDB blog:

- [Part 1](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)
- [Part 2](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)
- [Part 3](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)

In particular, look at the sample JavaScript code showing you how to do the application-level joins.

Comment: Thank you this is a great set of articles. So it seems that Mongoose's populate() essentially does the "application-level join"/dereferencing of the data.  Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly what populate() does. I'd suggest re-reading this page   <http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html> in light of what you've learned in the articles

Comment: What's not shown in the documentation is how the query is actually implemented.  Since the exec of the query comes after the populate functions I assume mongoose is optimizing the query perhaps into a single query rather than multiple and certainly not n+1. In a traditional rdbms the "populate" function should just do a single join. Since mongodb doesn't have joins I assume the populate is doing the $in clause in a secondary query (like you examples) rather than somehow combining the retrieval of the main table with the collection into a single query.

Comment: I don't know much about Mongoose.  The definition for populate() is here AFAICT: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/model.js#L2060-L2218